# Multiple NodeJs Express Server Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, cookies, jwt

I have 2 Express Servers on Port 3000 and 3001. I use nginx for routing domain.com to port 3000 and sub.domain.com top Port 3001. i have a Login Page on domain.com where users can Login with a random Username and a valid Code. Valid Codes are stored in a mongodb Database. If the entered Code was valid, the User gets authenticated and a jwt Token is stored into a Cookie. So far, it is working. After Authentication the User should be redirected to sub.domain.com/path. How can i send the Cookie when redirecting? Or ist there a better way the User stays authenticated?

I set the Cookie at domain.com, but cannot read it from sub.domain.com

Comment: Can you please share your node.js code for how you're setting your cookie?

Comment: @Garuuk <!-- language-all: lang-html --> `code   const token = jwt.sign(
          { username: username, password: password },
          jwtSecret,
          {
            expiresIn: maxAge, // 24hrs
          }
          
        );
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
          domain: '.localhost',
         /*  path: '/', */
          
        }); `

Comment: The Problem was because the Cookie didnt get passed in localhost. Changing the Domain from localhost to" something.local" did the job